# I dont think my tables are being created in SQLite

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to create tables into SQLite3 using python....
let me know what i am doing wrong here because nothing is being saved into my database...

```
def create_user_table():
    connection = sqlite3.connect("C:\\Users\erte\Desktop\Python\Valorank.db")
    c = connection.cursor()
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users
                (Username TEXT PRIMARY KEY,Password TEXT NOT NULL, RiotID TEXT)''')
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RANK
                (Userid TEXT PRIMARY KEY, CurrentMMR INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (Userid) REFERENCES users (Username))''')
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
    print("table created")

create_user_table()
```

I am not getting any error messages
I do get the table has been created message 
thank u

Comment: Try polulating the database and then query it. If there's an error, add that to the question, that will help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. I suspect the way you are verifying it is incorrect.

Open up your database and run `.schema` to see all the tables.

Here is an example of how I verified your code:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> def create_user_table():
...     connection = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
...     c = connection.cursor()
...     c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users
...                 (Username TEXT PRIMARY KEY,Password TEXT NOT NULL, RiotID TEXT)''')
...     c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RANK
...                 (Userid TEXT PRIMARY KEY, CurrentMMR INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (Userid) REFERENCES users (Username))''')
...     connection.commit()
...     connection.close()
...     print("table created")
... 
>>> create_user_table()
table created
>>> 
>>> import os
>>> os.system("sqlite3 test.db .schema")
CREATE TABLE users
                (Username TEXT PRIMARY KEY,Password TEXT NOT NULL, RiotID TEXT);
CREATE TABLE RANK
                (Userid TEXT PRIMARY KEY, CurrentMMR INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (Userid) REFERENCES users (Username));
0
>>>
```